# Normalization of volume

Tags: algorithmic-trading, standard-deviation, volume, normalization

suppose we have volumes every minute like below

```
100, 200 , 19,  0 , 200 , 12 , 100
```

I want to convert all these numbers to less than 10 , where 10 is max and 1 is min.

I can do this with normalisation but problem occurs when there is some sudden high volume comes like below

```
100, 200 , 19,  0 , 200 , 12 , 20000
```

where when I use normalization for past past 100 volumes, , this 20000 is affecting all other volumes.

Is there something I can do by taking averages of volumes and do normalisation for that or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is your model you can do anything. What I would do is use some dynamic outlier exclusion. For example in this case you know the min is zero.

One method (of many) might be to evaluate the median (since it might be more robust that the standard deviation or mean) and use 2 x median as your upper limit:

```
>>> arr = np.array([100,200,19,0,200,12,20000])
>>> upper_lim = np.median(arr) * 2
>>> arr_adj = np.where(arr>upper_lim, upper_lim, arr) / upper_lim
>>> arr_adj *= 10
>>> arr_adj
array([5, 10, 0.95, 0, 10, 0.6, 10])
```

Comment: That was brilliant , can you give me code in javascript for me ?

Comment: numpy is a python package designed for this type of efficient calculation. if you are interested in repeating in javascript you have to replicate each step. try here https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309447/calculating-median-javascript